# Can't use zsh shell in Catalina

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, catalina, zsh

When I opened Terminal after installing Catalina, this appeared:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

So I copy-pasted the code, it made me enter my password, but nothing happened.

```
bash-3.2$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for HomoErektus.
Password for HomoErektus: 
chsh: no changes made
bash-3.2$ echo $0
bash
```

I can't seem to find any answers. Nobody seems to have experienced this same issue. My User Login already has zsh as the default shell.

edit: terminal was fine the next day. Looks like terminal was just acting up. Guess the old "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" does work.

Comment: If no changes need to be made your default shell already is `zsh`. Can you check Terminal preferences (1st tab) to see whether it starts the default shell there or calls `bash` specifically?

Comment: Note that changing your login shell has no effect on existing shells. If you have a Terminal window open running bash, it's going to continue to run bash. Opening a new Terminal window will use the new setting (unless it's overridden in the Terminal preferences).

Answer (score 1):

Terminal has a setting to use the default shell or run any program.

I would make the election you wish:

[image]

If that's not it, you'll have to hunt down each of your initialization files. Before doing that, make a brand new user account to be sure you have a working zsh for that user and terminal overall.

It's probably the obvious item above, though.