# Why can't I use zsh?

Tags: terminal, catalina, zsh, macos

So I upgraded to Catalina. Actually it's more like a fresh install, I only copied across the few files I wanted to keep.

The shell is now helpfully telling me:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

The information on [that page](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT208050) helpfully shows GUI instructions which do not work. Specifically, it says "Control-click your user name in the list of users on the left, then choose Advanced Options.", but Control-click does nothing. So I reported that on the page.

When I use the suggested command instead:

```
hostname:~ username$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for username.
Password for username: 
chsh: Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.  Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.
chsh: no changes made
```

This is different to "[Can't use zsh shell in Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375884/)" because I get an error message that they don't.

It's also different to "[chsh: Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges](https://superuser.com/questions/1313038/)" because it seems that in their case, they were using iTerm. I'm using the default Terminal.app.

I have tried it with sudo just for laughs, but of course it does this, which makes perfect sense:

```
hostname:~ username$ sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh
Password: 
Changing shell for root.
```

So what's the deal here? How am I supposed to do it?

**Update:**

Well this *is* interesting. Two password prompts, and then a different error message about the parameter being invalid.

```
hostname:~ username$ sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh username
Password: 
Changing shell for username.
Password for username: 
chsh: One of the parameters provided was invalid.  One of the parameters provided was invalid.
chsh: no changes made
```

This error is new to me, but apparently it's new to Google as well, so I'm officially a trailblazer!

**Update: Happy New Year!**

Back in the office again.

Through poking at commands we had determined that Centrify was in use. Centrify comes with an `adupdate` tool which is supposed to be used to change user information. With the help of IT, we tried it, though, and were still denied, but now it's more like an error.

```
$ adupdate modify user -s /bin/zsh username
An error occurred while trying to modify a user while in Auto Zone.
The options (-d, -g, -i, -u, -s, -l, -m, -o, -X, -z) cannot be used during this operation.
Please consult the manual pages for more information.
```

First impressions: What is Auto Zone and how do I get out of it?

Comment: I'm not sure this helps, but the error message "One of the parameters provided was invalid" appears to come from Open Directory (the account etc info system macOS uses), and correspond to the error code `kODErrorRecordParameterError` and the "legacy code" `eParameterError` (see [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenDirectory/OpenDirectory-144/Core/errors.c.auto.html)). I think this indicates an invalid parameter is being passed to OD.

Comment: A work-around for this kind of nonsense (if you don't have sudo privileges and IT has broken chsh) is to have bash exec zsh on its startup profile so that zsh becomes the shell you end up in.  Be careful if you're trying this so you don't get in some kind of broken loop (you should be able to rename .bashrc (or whatever) in the Finder to revert back to the default situation. *Not tested on MacOS, but works on Linux/Unix*

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica this workaround might turn out to be the actual solution the way things are going. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging, finally a working solution!

```
$ sudo su -
# vim /etc/centrifydc/passwd.ovr
```

Added this line:

```
+username:::::::/bin/zsh:::::::
```

Saved, back to the shell...

```
# chmod 644 /etc/centrifydc/passwd.ovr
# adreload
# adflush
```

Logout from macOS and login again, and default shell is now zsh.

Comment: Aah - you’re not even using macOS - but centrify PAM to change how to manage accounts... (and also binding to AD presumably?)  Excellent work coming back with a solution - be sure to tick this if it’s the solve.

Answer (score 17):

@bmike has already offered the easiest solution, but I wanted to go back to the GUI instructions not working.

I found that Apple’s instructions here can be confusing. Control-Clicking will not do anything unless you first “unlock” the **Users & Groups** pane, as shown below in the blue box:

[image: screenshot of Users and Groups system preference pane.]

Once you have it unlocked, be sure you are clicking in the white-area on the left to access “Advanced Options…” as shown above with the blue arrow.

Then you should be able to access the options, including shell, from the Advanced pane.

Comment: This is easiest for people that don't want to learn / grok sudo and shell inheritance rules. I'd select this answer as "the one" tbh...

Comment: I'm in Catalina so it's now a black area, but I'm clicking in the black area and no menu is coming up. The padlock is showing as unlocked, so I'm still confused.

Comment: No, wait........ If I click on admin, I do get the menu. If I click on _my_ username, it doesn't pop up.

Comment: Admin user is type "Admin", my user is type "Admin, Network". Hypothesis is that advanced options isn't available to users authenticated from the network.

Comment: @Trejkaz Tell us more about your account. What kind of network domain is it coming from, and how is it set up?

Comment: @GordonDavisson As far as I know, it's an Active Directory domain. Beyond that...

Answer (score 15):

Don’t use sudo directly without some additional switches - your invocation  would change root’s shell, not your user account.

If your short name is mike (you can check with `whoami` or `who am i`

```
sudo -s
chsh /bin/zsh mike
```

Or if you know an admin short name and password you could skip the sudo initially

```
chsh -u admin /bin/zsh
```

@ me if you still have issues, there are a couple other ways to skin this cat, but I think once you specify the other user and su to root first, you should be set. It should have just worked out of the box, but hopefully we don’t have to go down that rabbit trail.

Comment: Wouldn't `sudo chsh /bin/zsh mike` do exactly the same thing?

Comment: Close: `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh mike` will do it.

Comment: This is definitely a lead. The new error message I'm getting looks suspiciously like our IT interfering with getting work done yet again. I updated the question with the new message.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat speculative answer, on the assumption that your account is coming from an Active Directory domain your Mac is bound to. You can check this by running:

```
dscl /Search -read /Users/"$USER" | grep AppleMetaNodeLocation
```

If it prints something like "`AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Active Directory/<somedomain>`", then your account is coming from AD, and this answer *might* work for you. I say "might" because I don't have a setup to test properly, and haven't messed with this stuff for several versions. If it doesn't print something about "/Active Directory/", this answer is not relevant.

Before proceeding further, I'd make a record of your current AD binding configuration. Run:

```
sudo dsconfigad -show
```

...and save its output somewhere, so you can refer to it if you need to put things back the way they were. If it doesn't print anything, then there's something weirder going on and I wouldn't recommend proceeding until you know what it is. It'll probably list something like "`Default user Shell = /bin/bash`"; if so, I'm pretty sure that's the root of your problem. To change this, run:

```
sudo dsconfigad -shell /bin/zsh
```

...and then probably reboot to make sure change takes effect. Oh, and check your Terminal preferences to make sure they're not overriding that (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375884/cant-use-zsh-shell-in-catalina)).

Explanation (if you care): in unix (including macOS), each user account record has an attribute that controls their default shell. Changing the user's shell (with `chsh` or whatever) edits the user's record to change that attribute value. But Active Directory accounts don't have this attribute (unless the AD domain has Identity Management for Unix enabled -- but that's [deprecated](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/activedirectoryua/2016/02/09/identity-management-for-unix-idmu-is-deprecated-in-windows-server/)), so Apple's AD connector fakes up a value for this on its own. Because it's fake, it can't really be changed. But you can change what value the AD connector uses to fake it up, and that's what the `dsconfigad` command does.

Comment: dsconfigad is a great tip, this shows me that I'm not joined using plain Active Directory at all (AppleMetaNodeLocation: /CentrifyDC/Default), but it gives me more things to Google which should hopefully get me somewhere. It might take some time fiddling.

Comment: @Trejkaz Ah, I'm only vaguely familiar with Centrify, but I'd guess it has its own options for controlling the user shell attribute.

Comment: Well done sussing out a PAM / domain binding was in play.